# JTextArea saving to txt

Tags: java, save, jtextarea

I'm making a program that requires to save user input. So I would like to know how to save JTextArea to text file and when you close and re-open program text is still in JTextArea.

Also sorry for my bad grammar.

```
package main;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class main extends JFrame {

JLabel statusbar;

public main() {

initUI();
}

public final void initUI() {

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
statusbar = new JLabel("");

statusbar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));

panel.setLayout(null);

JTextArea area1;

area1 = new JTextArea(90, 25);
area1.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 25);
area1.setBackground(Color.white);
area1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
area1.setText("");
panel.add(area1);


add(panel);
add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

setTitle("Viskis");
setSize(300, 200);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

JButton o = (JButton) e.getSource();
String label = o.getText();
statusbar.setText("");

} }

public static void main(String[] args) {

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

main ms = new main();
ms.setVisible(true);

new main();

}
});
}
}
```

Comment: Have you researched about files before asking your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some helper methods to help you read and write from Files. Look in the JavaDoc for [getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--) and [setText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText-java.lang.String-) for getting and setting the text of the JTextArea.

I recommend [reading the SwingWorker tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) and using these methods in a SwingWorker, lest you lock up your GUI while saving/reading the Files

```
/**
  * Writes a String text to a File specified by filename
  *
  * @param filename The filename/path of the File we would like to write the text to
  * @param text     The text to write to the File
  *
  */
public static void writeToFile(String filename, String text) {

    BufferedWriter writer = null; // This could go in a try-with-resources if you wanna get fancy

    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filename))); // Open a File for writing
        writer.write(text); // write the text to the file
    } catch ( IOException e) {

    /* We could not open the File for writing, or could not write to the File */

    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close(); // we are done writing to the File, close the connection
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        /* We could not close the connection to the File */

        }
    }
}

/**
  * Reads all lines from a File specified by filename
  *
  * @param filename The filename/path of the File we would like to read text from
  *
  * @return         An list of Strings containing each line of the File
  */
public static List<String> readFromFile(String filename) {

    BufferedReader reader = null; // This could go in a try-with-resources if you wanna get fancy
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename))); // Open a File for writing
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    /* We could not open the File for reading, or could not read from the File */

    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close(); // we are done reading from the File, close the connection
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        /* We could not close the connection to the File */

        }
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me with 'nam' as the current date and 'name' an input in a jTextField.

```
try {

         con=Connect.ConnectDB();         
         pst.execute();
         Date date=new Date();
         SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy-h-m-s");
         String nam= sd.format(date);
         String name=CaseNoField.getText();
         CaseNoField.setText("");

        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter( "C:\\path"+name+"("+nam+")"+".txt");      
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter( writer );
        JCaseArea.write( bw );
        bw.close();
        JCaseArea.setText("");
        JCaseArea.requestFocus();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Case Saved");
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write and read file on a swing  thread is not recommanded.  Use mvc pattern.  Create a data model with field binded to your component.  Create an adapter to update model and write file
Then your component will always up to date with your model

Use model to write data(with the adapter)  and read file will update your model with the adapter

For exemple,  Focus listener will call adapter to do the task. Or you can use an obseevee pattern when you Object if modified.